# How to manage disk space for Gromacs XTC (trajectory) file output

Tags: molecular-dynamics, high-performance-computing, gromacs

I'm running and MD run with this command:

```
gmx mdrun -v -deffnm md
```

It also produces trajectory file with `.xtc` extension.
Typically this file is extremely large, e.g. 143Gb for 1ns simulation and 143Tb for 10ns simulation.

My questions is the following:

**Is there an option in `gmx mdrun` to specify where to write the `.xtc` file?     For example I want to specify specific directory path with large disk space. Is there away to shrink the size of `.xtc` file?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Is there an option in `gmx mdrun` to specify where to write the `.xtc` file? For example I want to specify specific directory path with large disk space.

When you use the `-deffnm md` argument to `gmx mdrun`, it is assumed that all of the files will have the base name of `md`, so gromacs looks for `md.tpr` as input, and it writes `md.xtc`, `md.edr` etc. as output files in the current directory. This is not made clear in the documentation unfortunately.

To write the output files to other directories, you need to mention them explicitly. So, you need to run:

```
gmx mdrun -s md_01.tpr [-x /path/md_01.xtc] [-o md_01.trr] -c mdout.gro -g md_01.log -e md_01.edr
```

The `-s` argument supplies the binary topology input file (`.tpr`), the `-x` argument is for the compressed output, and `-o` for uncompressed output, so use whichever you selected in the `.mdp` file. The `-c`, `-g` and `-e` arguments provide the files for output coordinates, logfile and energy output file respectively. You can supply a file path for each of these arguments.

If you do not provide any of these arguments the default names would be used and the files would be written to the current working directory. The default names can be found [here](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2021/onlinehelp/gmx-mdrun.html).

> 2. Is there away to shrink the size of `.xtc` file?

This is difficult, there are three ways you can reduce the size of the file, and you have to change the MD settings by modifying the `.mdp` file.

One way is to change the frequency of writing the coordinates to the file i.e. increase the number of steps between writing to `.xtc` file by changing the value of the parameter `nstxout-compressed` in the `.mdp` file.

Another way is to decrease the precision of the coordinates written, using the parameter `compressed-x-precision` in the `.mdp` file. The default value is `1000`, which signifies 3-decimal point precision, so you can decrease that to `100` i.e. 2-decimal points.

There is also the setting `compressed-x-grps` which allow you to only write coordinates of a specific group into the trajectory file. This might be useful if you have for instance, a protein in solvent, and you only need information about the protein. [Here](https://manual.gromacs.org/archive/5.0.4/online/mdp.html) you can find an example where only the protein coordinates are being written to the `.xtc` file.

A detailed documentation of all of the `.mdp` options can be found [here](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2021/user-guide/mdp-options.html).

As an aside, an 143 GB output file for an 1 ns simulation seems unusually large. Your system likely has a large number of atoms, and you are storing coordinates every step. Usually, it is not necessary to do this. Consider the kind of analysis you need, and then adjust the saving frequency accordingly. For example, if you save coordinates each 2 ps ($\equiv2000$ steps if each timestep = 1 fs), then already you have 500 frames saved in your trajectory, which is sufficient for most common properties that can be analysed from a trajectory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very comprehensive response. I sincerely appreciate. I'm modeling peptide-protein binding. Peptide with 446 atoms and protein 4674 atoms.  You suggested `save coordinates each 2 ps` how can I control that in `mdp` file?

I only need to calculate RMSD and energy interaction analysis at the end.

Comment: @scamander If the time step for the integrator (`dt`) is 0.001 ps (=1 fs), which is the default in gromacs, then 2 ps is equivalent to 2000 steps. So, in the `mdp` file, set `nstxout-compressed = 2000`. (It will write to the xtc once every 2000 steps) I think that 500 frames are probably okay for RMSD, I've never done energy interaction analysis before, so I don't know about that. In any case, you can change the save coordinate frequency to get more frames if you need to.